# One Page Scroll Dots Navigation in Javascript and jQuery based url with smooth transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So far I managed to create a One Page Scroll Dots Navigation that does the following:

Adds the "current" class on the link you click and takes you to that link.
 This is what happens in html when you click the link Team, it adds the class="current".

```
<li class="current"><a href="#firstproject-team">Team</a></li>
```

I would need help to make the transition smoothly when clicking a specific link instead of taking me directly there, like it's happening.

Also I would need to update the class="current" based on the section id I am currently at when scrolling.

Here is my current code: https://jsfiddle.net/tqhykbbn/10/

Looks like Javascript is not working here but it should as on my local computer is working and I uploaded jQuery in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your links to page anchors aren't working is because you've put a hash symbol when assigning an id, which is incorrect syntax. This is correct `<div id="firstproject-about">` **without** the `#`.

For a smooth transition there's a few solutions. Check out, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/